# With Julia Symbolics, can I solve for a variable in an equation?

Tags: julia, symbolic-math

I would like to solve for `a` in `y = √((a^2 + b^2))`

What I tried:

```
julia> using Symbolics

julia> @variables a b
(a, b)

julia> y = √((a^2 + b^2))
sqrt(a^2 + b^2)

julia> eq = y = √((a^2 + b^2))
sqrt(a^2 + b^2)

julia> eq
sqrt(a^2 + b^2)
```

And then to solve, I tried:

```
julia> Symbolics.solve_for(eq,[a])
julia> Symbolics.solve_for(eq,a)
julia> Symbolics.solve_for(y,[a])
julia> Symbolics.solve_for(y,a)
```

which all resulted in the error:

```
ERROR: type Num has no field rhs
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems in your code. The first one is that an equation should have two parts, right hand side (i.e. `rhs`) and left hand side (i.e. `lhs`). Your error message clearly points out the problem: `sqrt(a^2 + b^2)` is a `Num` type since `a` and `b` are variables of `Num` since they will (supposed to) evaluate to numbers. In Symbolics.jl, the way to declare an equation is to use `~`. So the right way to express your equation is

```
@variables a b y
eq = y ~ √((a^2 + b^2))
```

However unfortunately Symbolics.jl cannot solve it for you now since `solve_for` can only resolve system of linear equations, just as the document says

> Currently only works if all equations are linear. check if the expr is linear w.r.t vars.

So it will throw `AssertionError: islinear(ex, vars)` error. However you can try out this function using some simple equation like `a+b`.

```
julia> eq = y ~ a+b
y ~ a + b
Symbolics.solve_for([eq],[a])
1-element Vector{Num}:
 y - b
```

BTW:

You can turn off the linearity check with `check=false` parameter, but it's almost guaranteed that Symbolics.jl will give you a wrong result. For example, the Symbolics.jl says the result of equation `y ~ √((a^2 + b^2))` is `a + y*sqrt(a^2 + b^2)*(a^-1) - ((a^-1)*(sqrt(a^2 + b^2)^2))`.